# Using TransactionScope with Stored Procedure Transaction does not work

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, transactionscope, msdtc

As per my understanding, C# `TransactionScope` can still work when wrapping a T-SQL `BEGIN / COMMIT TRANSACTION` inside a stored procedure.

I have the following C# method which does `EF Save` first, then call a stored procedure that has its own transaction and then call external service over HTTP

```
public async Task DoSomething(MyDto dto)
{
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //Save First
            var myEntity = await _dbContext.MyEntity.Where(x=>x.Id == dto.Id).SingleOtDefaultAsync();

            // Assign properties here from dto to MyEntity and then save entity             
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            // call stored procedure that has its own transaction
            _dbContext.prcDoExtraWork(dto.Id);

            // call external service using Http             
            await _httpClient.PostAsync(url,somecontent)

            scope.Complete();
        }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcDoExtraWork]
    @ID INT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;     

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            // modify data and  inserts records into tables
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        SELECT 1 AS `Result`
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (XACT_STATE() <> 0)
        BEGIN       
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

            IF @ErrorMessage IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SET @ProcName = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
                SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
                SET @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();
                SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
                SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
            END

            EXEC prcErrorHandler @ProcName = @ProcName, 
                                 @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage, 
                                 @ErrorSeverity = @ErrorSeverity,
                                 @ErrorState = @ErrorState, 
                                 @ErrorNumber = @ErrorNumber

            SELECT 0 AS `Result`
        END
    END CATCH

    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
END
```

**Issue 1:** the call of the external service over http fails, my expectation was whatever records stored procedure has inserted or modified will ROLLBACK.

However that is not happening. I still see the new records in the database

**Issue 2**

To solve the error above I had to enable TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption since i am using async methods

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {

     // do your stuff
     scope.complete();
   }
```

However now on scope.complete() i get error

> The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are
>   pending requests working on this transaction
>
> System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has
>   aborted. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction
>   operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests
>   working on this transaction.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[]
>   buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName,
>   TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout,
>   SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
>   Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest
>   transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso,
>   SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean
>   isDelegateControlRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment
>   enlistment)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.EndCommit(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()    at
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.d__343.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at XXXXXXXXXXXXX.MyDetailController.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)

Answer (score 1):

I think i found it.
The first issue i solved by enabling `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` since i am using async methods

```
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {

         // do your stuff
         scope.complete();
       }
```

The second issue
The stored proc was returning 1 or 0 based on success or error. The C# code does not care the value of the return result however i was not evaluating the return result from stored proc. So to solve i have to call 'SingleOrDefault`

`_dbContext.prcDoExtraWork(dto.Id).SingleOrDefault()`