# TransactionScope.Complete() returns error

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, transactionscope

I am facing some strange error while executing following code.

I debugged all methods and found no error but `scope.Complete();` line returns an error **"Transaction has aborted"** and `InnerException` is **"The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION."**

`InsertEntries(myObject)` calls few more methods within for making entries to near about 12-15 different tables in SQL Server. It used StoredProcedues to do that.

I am using EntityFramework and SQLServer.

NOTE:

1 - Everything works fine without `TransactionScope`.

2 - Error returns on `scope.Complete();` line. No other errors.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope()
 {
     try
     {
        myObject.IsMain = false;
        InsertEntries(myObject);
        myObject.IsDuplicateNumber = IsDuplicateNumber;
        myObject.RecNum = RecNum;
        myObject.NextNumber = nextNumber;
        scope.Complete(); 
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you call db.SaveChanges?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157861/using-transactionscope-with-stored-procedure-transaction-does-not-work

Comment: For Entity Framework why aren't you using [context.Database.BeginTransaction()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions)?

Comment: Probably something in `InsertEntries` or a stored procedure rolled back the transaction.  Are you sure there aren't any exceptions being thrown?